# Passing lambda expression to LINQ Include() (SharePoint CSOM)

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, lambda, parameter-passing

I have tried searching but I don't seem to find any relevant answers. Perhaps because I'm not really sure how to formulate my question.

I'm writing a class library to aid working with SharePoint's Client Side Object Model. When executing a query, one can specify which properties of returned objects should be loaded, in order to avoid unnecessary network traffic. This is done by the means of Lambda Expression.

Here is an example that works:

```
public ListItemCollection GetItems(
                params Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>[] retrievals)
{
   var query = new CamlQuery {...};
   ListItemCollection queryResults = _list.GetItems(query);
   ReloadClientObject(queryResults, retrievals)
   return queryResults;
}

public void ReloadClientObject<T>(T clientObject,
          params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals)
          where T : ClientObject
{
   _context.Load(clientObject, retrievals);
   _context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Example call:

```
var items = GetItems(items => items.Include(
                                         item => item.Id,
                                         item => item.DisplayName));
```

This would all be fine. But I'd rather return `IEnumerable<ListItem>` instead of `ListItemCollection` and I would like to pass parameters of type `Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>` instead of `Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>`... not to introduce the user to the `ListItemCollection` at all. **So I'd like to move the `Include()` call to the body of my method**... and that's where I got stuck.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> GetItems(
                          params Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] retrievals)
{
   var query = new CamlQuery {...};
   ListItemCollection queryResults = _list.GetItems(query);
   ReloadClientObject(queryResults, items => items.Include(retrievals))
   _context.ExecuteQuery();
   return queryResults.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Example call (much cleaner and nicer):

```
var items = GetItems(item => item.Id, item => item.DisplayName));
```

However, this throws `OperationNotSupportedException` when calling the `Load()` method.

I would be grateful for any guidance. Thank you!

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: I believe it was empty... or generally not helpful.

Comment: Don't you want `items => items.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.DisplayName })`. I didn't read your question closely but it looks like you're trying to use `Include` to do a projection when `Select` is made for that exact purpose.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal By having an anonymous object, instead of an actual `ListItem`, you couldn't, for example, update the item.

Comment: Using the latter code you provided it works as expected for me; it doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: @Servy You are right. I wanted to simplify it as much as possible... But I've actually simplified it so much that I've eliminated the issue. Sorry about that. I've updated the code examples so now they should represent the problem accurately.

Answer (score 3):

Call `Include` directly on the query itself, and then just use `LoadQuery` instead of `Load`, to load the query:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> GetItems(this ClientContext context,
    string listName,
    params Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] retrievals)
{
    var query = new CamlQuery();

    var queryResults = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName)
        .GetItems(query)
        .Include(retrievals);
    context.LoadQuery(queryResults);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    return queryResults;
}
```

---

Since that doesn't work for you (according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245624/passing-lambda-expression-to-linq-include-sharepoint-csom/21245754#comment32005901_21245754) stating that you need to leverage the paging functionality) we'll need to do a bit more work.

So what we'll do here is create a `Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, ItemSelector, object>>` that will take a collection, a selector, and map that to an object.  Here `ItemSelector` is defined through `using ItemSelector = Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>;`  (Because trying to use a `Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>, object>>` is just cruel and unusual punishment).  We can define it like so:

```
Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, ItemSelector, object>> includeSelector =
    (items, selector) => items.Include(selector);
```

Now what we can do is write an `Apply` method that can take an expression of a function taking two parameters, replace all instances of the second parameter with the constant, and thus create a method with one less parameter.  Here is the definition of that `Apply` method:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> Apply<T1, T2, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> expression,
    T2 value)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(
        expression.Body.Replace(expression.Parameters[1],
            Expression.Constant(value))
        , expression.Parameters[0]);
}
```

This uses this helper method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}

internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

So now we can take this `includeSelector` expression and, for each item selector in our array, apply that selector to this function.  Taking those results and putting them into an array gives us an `Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>[]`, which is exactly what we need to pass to `Load`.

Whew.  Here is the final code to actually do that:

```
public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetItems(this ClientContext context,
    string listName,
    params Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] retrievals)
{
    var query = new CamlQuery();

    var queryResults = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName)
        .GetItems(query);

    Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, ItemSelector, object>> includeSelector =
        (items, selector) => items.Include(selector);

    context.Load(queryResults, retrievals
        .Select(selector => includeSelector.Apply(selector))
        .ToArray());
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    return queryResults;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work. I have not mentioned that I'm also using `ListItemCollectionPosition` property of the `ListItemCollection` and specifying RowLimit in the query in order to implement "paging" to transfer less data at once. When using LoadQuery(), I no longer have the `ListItemCollectionPosition` available (I don't get `ListItemCollection`). Good point, though.

Comment: @nixx See the edit for a solution that will work for you.  Note that it looks somewhat more intimidating than it really is; you just need to be able to break it down to each small piece, which isn't too too hard to analyze in isolation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is some progress, but unfortunately, I still get "The query expression is not supported" exception. I compared the expression passed directly and via the parameter in the debugger and though they appear to be the same, they are not. I've posted the comparison here: http://pastebin.com/fhq3YReN

Comment: Another difference is how multiple selectors are handled. First (top) example is the direct one (working) the other is the passed using the Apply() method: http://imgur.com/a/hctZh

Comment: What is "ItemSelector"? This class does not get resolved in my .NET core console project. Also @nixx , did it work?

Comment: @Patric The second paragraph after the horizontal break defines `ItemSelector`.

Comment: @Servy ok, I missed that one, but I am still not getting it and I don't get it to compile. Normally using needs parenthesis like "using (var x = ...)". You write "using ItemSelector = Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>;". Why is ItemSelector capitalized, is it a class or a var? Also in the last code block, the static GetItems method uses this "ItemSelector" class or var but the using you mentioned is not inside this method, so how can this work?

Comment: @Patric It's a [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), not a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: @Servy ah, of course, you are right. I mixed it up. I now haven an issue with the GetItems method. Which I call like "GetItems(items => items.Include(item => item.Folder))". It tells me that "'ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Include'..", I added already "using System.Linq;" to the class but it doesn't help. Do you know what might be missing?

Comment: @Patric The whole point of the answer is to not have to write out "items.Include", but rather to pass in a list of item selectors, rather than item *collection* selectors, and to have this method turn them into the proper selectors.  If you want to be providing selectors for a list item collection, there's no need for this answer at all.

Comment: @Servy I made a fallacy, you are right. In my case it was okay to stick with ListItemCollection and pass the retrievals into it as shown in the question. Only tricky part was (at first), that with retrievals the ListItemCollectionPostion is no longer automatically populated which I add now "manually" to the retrievals if there are any.